# Using scala object inside java?

Tags: java, scala, loops, type-conversion

In my java code, I am calling a method, from a class which is defined in Scala, and I want to use one of its methods in java. Here is how I call it and it works fine.

```
Seq<SomeObjectType> variableName = ScalaClass.MethodInTheScalaClass();
```

I can call this function in java in this form, but since I am calling this method from a compiled package, I can't see what it going on (and therefore I can't change it).

The problem now is that, I don't know how to iterate over the "variableName" in java (since Seq is a scala type).

How can I iterate over variableName or convert it to a Java object (e.g. List)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
java.util.List<SomeObjectType> res = 
  scala.collection.JavaConverters$.MODULE$.seqAsJavaListConverter(variableName).asJava();
```

You could get converters list in [JavaConverters documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.JavaConverters$).

You should use `JavaConverters$.MODULE$` to get `JavaConverters` object from `Java`.

Comment: Thank you! So, if I have only java (no scala) everything should work perfectly fine; right?

Comment: @Daniel: you'll need `scala` lib, but you'll need it anyway to use `ScalaClass`. In case you have plenty of such `scala` methods to use in `java` code I'd recommend you to create java-friendly `ScalaClassJavaApi` wrapper using `scala` - you could use scala in any maven java project using [scala-maven-plugin](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html).